# Oracle SQL Developer debugger doesn't show the "outside values"

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I´m debugging a PL/SQL package that has some variables declared in the SPEC.

The debug first dialog allows us to choose one specific procedure and gives a PL/SQL block that calls for this procedure.

During the debug session the "data" view shows the values of the parameters and the inside declared variables.
But related to the variables declared in the SPEC (outside the actual procedure), even they being used in this procedure, this same view "data" doesn't show the values. And when I use the "watches" view it only shows question marks instead of the actual values. I tried to reference the outer variables like this 'PK_name.variable_name' ,but it didn't work.
According to this link this was already stated, but it seems that it wasn't fixed yet.
https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/debugging-in-sqldeveloper-how-can-i-watch-the-entry-of-vari-4809

Any tips?

I´m using Oracle SQL Developer IDE  version 22.2.1.234.1810

Comment: make sure the 'external' plsql programs are ALSO compiled for DEBUG

Comment: Including the SPEC?

Comment: i think so, yes